# How do I transfer iPhone contacts to an Android phone?

Tags: contacts, data-transfer

I know someone who just got an Atrix 4G and previously had an iPhone 3GS. I was asked how he could move his contacts from the iPhone/iTunes onto the Android device. I have never owned an iPhone and have had limited interaction with them. Does anyone know the simplest method of getting iPhone contacts onto an Android device?

Comment: You can sync the iPhone contacts to iCloud. Then, use your PC to log in to iCloud in order to export them all in a single VCF file. Ultimately, import the VCF into Gmail and voila!

Comment: I just saw that you are using iPhone 3GS. If you don't have an iCloud account, export the contacts directly via your PC: http://www.copytrans.net/support/how-to-transfer-contacts-from-iphone-to-android/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd probably suggest using [Google Sync](http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?answer=138740&topic=14252) to sync the iPhone contacts with the Google account, then using that account for the Android.

Comment: Probably the best way, I can't find a simple way to export iPhone contacts to .vcf.

Comment: Is there any way to dump them to a simpler format like CSV? GMail will happily import a big CSV of Contacts.

Comment: I just got word that Google sync worked well for him, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest method I've found has been using a desktop/browser. [Here's an article explaining how](http://www.tomjepson.co.uk/transfer-contacts-iphone-to-google-contacts/), but for the recap:

1. Make sure that the you are using iClound and that the contacts sync setting is on.
2. Log into https://www.icloud.com/ with your iTunes details and select "Contacts".
3. Select all contacts. The article suggests scrolling, but it's quicker to select the first one and use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (or <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> for Mac).
4. Select "Export vCard..." from the cog icon in the bottom left of the screen.
5. Log into [Google Contacts](https://www.google.com/contacts/) and select "Import..." from the "More" menu.
6. Upload/import your vCard and merge duplicates.

That's it! Pretty much as soon as you've imported and de-duplicated you should see your contacts start showing on your phone. You may want to delete the extra Group that's added but it's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been solved already, but I just faced the same problem and found an easy solution that maybe helps someone else. If you don't really like going over Google Contacts to sync from iPhone to Android, you can also use "Bump". It's a small application that works on both platforms and works perfectly between the two. I just ended up moving all my contacts in a simple bump ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an app that transfers the contacts via bluetooth or wi-fi, [this one](http://www.appstorehq.com/vcard--bluetoothvcfexchange-iphone-42007/app), for example.