# Copy contacts from iCloud to Android phone

Tags: contacts, data-transfer

Just went from an iPhone to an Android phone. How do I get my contacts that I have on iCloud on to my Android phone?

I looked at SmoothSync, but what's the point in paying for that when I know there is a free way such as as doing it manually.

Comment: See also: [How do I transfer iPhone contacts to an Android phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/7358/16575) and [How can I transfer my contacts from an iPhone to an Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/18796/16575)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you still have the iPhone in order to get the contacts off of it - There are free applications such as ["my Contacts Backup"](http://mycontactsbackup.globile.biz/) for iPhone that will export all your contacts. This particular one exports them as .VCF (i.e. vcards) and / or .CSV and then emails them to you. I'm sure there are other apps out there too to use, but I went with this one as it's free.

You can then import the vcard file into your Google / Gmail contacts via PC and then sync your contacts from Google onto your device.

[image]

Shouldn't take more than 5 minutes end to end.

Answer (score 0):

You could go http://icloud.com and click on "Contacts", there you can click on the cog in the bottom left corner. You will have the option to "Export vCard", with that vCard, you can import it into Google Contacts, similarly to what JonW said.